# How to use BDC (business Data Catalog) in sharepoint of user define?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, bdc

I have database in sql server 2008. I have installed the MOSS 2007 also configured the Sared services. I want to Use BDC concept to show the data on sharepoint pages by its web parts. What steps I have to follow for this? I searched for this also on several sites. But something XML with LOB I have to define. What is this exact. how can i define LOB xml for my database from sql server 2008 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be of use:

http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/everything-you-need-to-know-about-bdc-part-1-of-8

Pretty complex stuff, but this provides some good information.